# Drug abuse in the Holy Land?

Tags: christianity, drugs

Was there prevalent drug abuse in the Holy Land at the time Jesus lived? If so, what drug would that be?

By "abuse" I mean use of large quantities of the drug over time which may have had mind altering effects.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Have you looked at Dioscorides' [De Materia Medica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Materia_Medica), for example? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Many thanks for your comment! I am not a historian, so I have not done research into this topic. You suggest Dioscorides' De Materia Medica, and i will have a look

Comment: Strongly relevant question and answer: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/48990/whats-the-earliest-evidence-of-drug-abuse

Comment: You should really define what you understand "abuse" to be. As is this is a fighting word of prohibitionists. If you just think of "use" of psychoactive substances (anything other than alcohol, obviously), then please use "use". If you think of problems arising from that, use something like "overdoing it"? Looking forward to your [edit].

Comment: @LangLangC: Yes, humans have USED psychoactive substances pretty much as long as they've been human, if not before, and still do.  (I write this as I go for my morning's second cup of psychoactive substance :-))

Comment: The poppy and the Hebrews

The Hebrews, as a people living in an area where the poppy and its juice were known from remote antiquity, cannot but have been cognizant of their uses.

Many studies have been made on the plants of the area, and are included in certain books of the Bible, and particularly in the Talmud.

Professor Marti [ 136] of Switzerland has studied these and avers that among them are included the papaver somniferum or setigerum (seeds and oil).

Rindley [ 137] (1900) mentions various plants from the Bible and among them " rosch " (head), which he interprets as being

Comment: the capsule of the papaver setigerum. This, according to him, was the gall mixed with vinegar which the Hebrews gave to Christ on the cross in order to alleviate His suffering.

Furthermore Miss Walker [ 138] states that the gall which was added to the vinegar was the juice of the hypnotic poppy, called rosch in Hebrew.

Comment: From here: https://www.unodc.org/unodc/en/data-and-analysis/bulletin/bulletin_1967-01-01_3_page004.html#s290

Comment: The last comments should be part of your question and reasoning for asking. Please [edit] them in. They look quit essential, and comments are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly wine or fortified wines and beer. Other drugs did exist, but nowhere near what we have today. Distillation wasn't invented yet, so strong alcoholic beverages didn't exist. Fortified wines did, but that doesn't involve distillation.

It's possible some *(read: very few)* people used herbs, mushrooms or even hemp, but not in great quantities. It wasn't mainstream then. I doubt very much if people smoked hemp, smoking wasn't discovered as yet.

[Opium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium#Ancient_use_(pre-500_CE)) did exist (poppies), but not as processed opium. It was used at least by the Greeks and Romans for medical purposes. Perhaps some people used it for recreational purposes. As a natural unprocessed product the effects are far less than using the processed product.

Comment: '_Opium did exist (poppies), but not as processed opium_'. In fact, Dioscorides - writing in the first century CE - describes [harvesting opium](https://archive.org/details/de-materia-medica_/page/n637) using essentially the same method as is used today.

Comment: *"Fortified wines did, but that doesn't involve distillation."* Fortified wines are [created by adding distilled alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortified_wine) to wine. Do you have a source for another way of making them?

Comment: @John Dallman Maybe frozen distillation, but it is only suspected.

Comment: @JohnDallman I know fortified wines existed. Sulla drank it, I read somewhere. How they made it, I don't know.

Comment: @Jos: if you mean Sulla the Roman dictator, he definitely had access to a wider range of products than the average resident of the Holy Land.

Comment: You are thinking of chandu or directly smokeable opium. Back then opium *is* already processed, and that is fermented, but would have needed a carrier, or eg thrown onto hot stones for inhalation. But why fixate on this? Eating and drinking it was available.

Comment: @AlbertoYagos: The climate of the Holy Land is not very suitable for freeze-distillation. It isn't *impossible*, but it's unlikely to be a regular process.

Comment: @JohnDallman Fortified wines weren't regular either. But before distillation, the only method I know they made them was through freeze-distillation in mountains.

Comment: https://www.unodc.org/unodc/en/data-and-analysis/bulletin/bulletin_1967-01-01_3_page004.html#s290

Comment: @sempaiscuba opium was known, but the processing into things like heroin wasn't (afaik). Raw poppy seeds and milk may well have been used.

Comment: @jwenting Heroin wasn't developed until the 19th century. However, we know from Diagoras that opium was inhaled (presumably using something like an incense burner) at least as early as the 3rd century BCE. If you're interested, there is an interesting [paper](https://www.unodc.org/unodc/en/data-and-analysis/bulletin/bulletin_1967-01-01_3_page004.html) on the history of poppies & opium in antiquity in the eastern Med. We know that poppies, and probably opium, were used as far back as the Bronze Age, but evidence for their _recreational_ use only begins to emerge in the classical period.

Comment: For example: [The Use of Opium in the Bronze Age in the Eastern Mediterranean](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23462630?seq=1/profile)

Comment: @sempaiscuba interesting, so they used opium and derived drugs in various ways, and already knew about its use as a pain killer as well several thousand years before Christ. Pretty much guaranteed the Israelites and Romans used it as well around the time of Christ, unless religious restrictions were in place (which is quite possible especially among the Jews, I'm no expert on Judaism).

Comment: @jwenting Yes, it was almost certainly used, although presumably not on a large enough scale that it was considered to be a serious problem since we have no record of any authorities trying to prevent it (unlike the Dionysian rites involving alcohol consumption, which were periodically banned in Rome). Which then raises the question of whether it was considered to be 'drug abuse' as we understand the term.

Comment: @sempaiscuba almost certainly no drug abuse, which is a legal term. From papers I can see it being used mainly in medical and religious procedures. And from the paper you linked it seems likely it wasn't cultivated on any scale.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:**
>   Was there prevalent drug abuse in the Holy Land at the time Jesus lived? If so, what drug would that be?

.

> **[Matthew 27:34](https://biblehub.com/matthew/27-34.htm)**,
>   There they offered Jesus wine to drink, mixed with gall; but after tasting it, he refused to drink it.

During Jesus's crucifixion, Matthew and Mark report the offer of doped wine by the Roman guards who had a container of the drink. Matthew calls it wine mixed with **Gall**. This was not actual gall, but the drink was so called because of its bitter taste. **[Mark 15:23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+15%3A23&version=NIV)**, reports that the drink was wine mixed with myrrh.   Myrrh was added to the wine in order to give it more potency.  This was likely done to weaken the victim and make the execution go faster.  Crucifixion was a long slow death where the victim eventually suffocates over many hours as his chest muscles eventually exhaust themselves supporting the victim's weight.  The wine was probable offered by the guards, to shorten their watch and speed up the ordeal.  If one weren't being crucified the mixture would be recreational and enhance the stupefying effect of the alcohol.

The old testament also talks of "water of gall" which I found references to as water of poppy the plant opium is refined from; but those don't appear in the new testament.

- Deuteronomy 29:18
- Jeremiah 9:15; 8:14 ; 23:15
- Lamentations 3:19

**Sources:**

- **[Bible Study: Gall](https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionary/gall/)**
- **[Mark 15:23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+15%3A23&version=NIV)**
- **[Matthew 27:34](https://biblehub.com/matthew/27-34.htm)**